# Pandas replace escape character '/'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace `/` using pandas and it looks like I'm facing a problem since it does not affect my DataFrame. I do realize the possible problem may be due to the fact a character `/` is used to escape a string in python... but how can I change the code to replace character - / to just a space... ?

Many thanks for any tips in advance.

```py
Data['DESCRIPTION'] = Data['DESCRIPTION'].str.replace('/', ' ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
Data['DESCRIPTION'] = Data['DESCRIPTION'].str.replace(r'/', ' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Data['DESCRIPTION'] = Data['DESCRIPTION'].str.replace('//', ' ')
```

Since it is used to escape as you said, you need to add one additional one so it knows what to replace

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.DataFrame.replace)

> It is inteded to replace the entire value, not a part of string.

If you want to replace a sub string, you can  either use Series' `str.replace` like this:

```py
Data['DESCRIPTION'] = Data['DESCRIPTION'].str.replace(r'/', ' ')
```

or,

you can just apply pythons' `replace` method with `lmabda` like this:

```py
Data['DESCRIPTION'] = Data['DESCRIPTION'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('/',' ')
```

Or,

You can just use `str.replace` to avoid using lambda:

```py
Data['DESCRIPTION'] = Data['DESCRIPTION'].apply(str.replace, args=('/', ' '))
```